# Grails: Difference in behavior between run-war and run-app

Tags: facebook, json, grails

I am using the FB cookie and trying to decode it into json, the code looks similar to this

```
    def value = cookie.value

    String[] tokens = value.split('\\.')
    String decodeToken = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(tokens[1].getBytes()), 
            'UTF-8')
    def jsonValue = JSON.parse(decodeToken)
```

Where the cookie is the one that facebook creates when using the login plugin.

Now, when I run this using run-app, there are no issues. However, when running it using run-war, an exception is thrown when the JSON parser tries to create the JSON object from the String.

> Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at character 304 of {"algorithm":"HMAC-SHA256","code":"AQCvjV......."user_id":...50089"\00\00

Debugging it further, it seems the String that gets created from the decode call, is fine when run in the context of run-app. But when run-war is done, the last character of the String is not a '}' but some garbled character - and this is the one that causes the parser to throw an exception.

What could be a cause of this? What would be a good point to start debugging this further?

I have even tried to invoke getBytes() by using a specific encoding - but to no avail.

Comment: Had exactly same problem, but don't remember how i've fixed it :( My current code looks exactly same as yours

Comment: Igor - I was using your plugin (spring-security-facebook) when I ran across this problem. Since then I have tried everything short of rewriting the plugin (which is why the code looks so similar, I am sure :-) ). Anything you can do to recall how you fixed it would be so helpful!

Comment: Heh :) seems that it's still same old problem :) ok, maybe we can try to find reason together? do you have an working example to reproduce? you can send it to igor@artamonov.ru

Comment: Sounds good - I am at the moment trying to put my application back part by part to see if I can identify at what point the application throws the error . The interesting thing is that this problem has not hit so far - very strange!

Comment: I have idea that it can be because of a very specific cookie value

Comment: So, I built up the application part by part. It failed finally when I added the richui plugin. So, at the moment it seems the plugin does something to make this portion fail when in a war. I will try to see if I can put together a bare-bones application and make it fail there as well. If I can make fail, will email it to you. Thanks for the support!

Comment: Ok, or also you can send me just cookie value

Answer (score 0):

run-app runs a grails applications and allows the reloading from resources

run-war generates a war file and runs the war file, so no reloading of resources.

you could manually do grails war and then run it on a local instance of tomcat.

Comment: I have the same problem using a war file on a local instance of tomcat. It is almost as if the minute the code runs inside a war, the bytes change - though why that should be, I am not clear.